# execute javascript before XML Request

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm not very used to xml requests, but is there a way to execute code before a XMLHttpRequest. What I'm trying to do is, Send a request and open a new url. But since this takes a few seconds and I got a few requests at once, I want a loading screen to appear while sending requests. Here is my code so far:

```
function sendRequests(){

    url = "placeholder";
    url2 = "placeholder2";

    displayObject("loadingScreen");

    var xmlHttpCart = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpCart.open( "GET", url, true ); 
    xmlHttpCart.send( null );

    window.open(url2,"_self");
}

function displayObject(i) {
    var id = "" + i;
    document.getElementById(i).style.display = "inherit";
}
```

Unfortunately the displayObject() function is triggered after the request is finished.

thanks

Comment: No, `displayObject` is triggered before the `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: But why is the style attribute changed after the request is finished?

Comment: That depends on your code. We do not have enough information

Comment: I edited my question to display my complete function and my displayObject function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will finish running the JavaScript until it finishes whatever it is doing. This blocks repainting the display.

> ```
> xmlHttpCart.open( "GET", url, false ); // false for synchronous request
> ```

This is one example of why using `false` there is deprecated and **you should not do that**.

Comment: hmm... tried that with synchronious as well with asynchronious request, but got the same result at first. Now I tried again, and suddenly it seems to work. Thanks for letting me try again. But now, I have the problem, that i will leave the page, before all requests are handled...